# ClassPath not found Spring Boot only on Docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

the java code below allows you to insert values in a java report to then create a pdf file, when I run the code below I have the following error: Classpath resource not found when running as jar, what is it due to and how I solve this problem?

**java code:**

```
  ClassPathResource reportResource = new ClassPathResource("templates/printcantiere.jasper");
            Map<String, Object> reportParameters = new HashMap<>();
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource itemsJRBean = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tablevalues);
            reportParameters.put("ItemDataSource", itemsJRBean);
            reportParameters.put("RagioneSociale", c.getRagioneSociale());
            reportParameters.put("Commessa", c.getCommessa());
            reportParameters.put("NomeCantiere", c.getNomeCantiere());
            reportParameters.put("Stato", c.getStatoCantiere());
```

**docker.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#Kill process on port
kill -9 $(lsof -ti:8081)
#delete old jar file and regenerate jar file
mvn clean package
rm -rf test/*.jar
mvn clean install
#generate new jar file mvn clean package
mvn eclipse:eclipse
#define docker name
dockername=quote
#Delete all containers and all volumes
#docker system prune -a
#Build of container and image
docker rm $dockername
docker build -t $dockername .
#Run container
docker run --publish 8081:8081 $dockername
```

**Dockefile:**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk16
ARG JAR_FILE=target/report-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

[Pom file link](https://gist.github.com/riccardopirani/b8f04e8a2d988f54dfa60226ab800ec8)

Comment: Can you add more details? like your `pom.xml` or `gradle.build` also adding more context to Java code is helpful

Comment: @hatefalipoori i have add link to pom file